# WPF TextAlignment doesn't work inside a TextBlock in a Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a button in WPF similar as the one in Amazon's checkout cart as shown below:

[image: checkout quantity Button]

My attempted button is generated dynamically, but it's equivalent to the following XAML

```
<Button Name="UpDownBtn">
    <Grid >
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="numCopiesTxt" Padding="3" FontSize="20">123</TextBlock>
      </Viewbox>
      <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="20" Text="v"/>
      </Viewbox>
  </Grid>
</Button>
```

where v in Marlett Font represents the upAndDown arrow.

However, the `TextAlignment="Right"` doesn't seem to make it right (no pun intended) whether Viewbox is used or not. Why is it this? Shown below

With Viewbox
[image: with view box]
without Viewbox
[image: without Viewbox]

---

(Updated: PLEASE IGNORE Question #2. This was because the height of the Grid was set to `Auto`, not `*`. The XAML above does not cause this problem.)

*2. When a `Button` (with `Viewbox`) is added to a `Grid`, the Button is so big that only part of the content is shown inside its designated grid cell; the rest stops at the grid line. Note that the `Viewbox` does make the `TextBlock`s fit to the grid cells *inside* the Button, but the Button doesn't fit to its designated grid cell. This only happens with the use of Viewbox.*

thanks!

Comment: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown

Comment: I've tried it, but its up and down arrows are too small. Also, the input might be too large to increment one by one. What i want is similar to Amazon's Quantity button in the shopping cart, where the up and down arrows and the number are on the same button.

Comment: Trying to reply to your point#2 (if I really understood the question): when you add your Button to a Grid you can specify Margin property to fit the Button in the way you like. Otherwise you can use Width and Height Properties.

Comment: @Riccardo thanks for pointing me to that direction. I just realized that i was using "auto" instead of "*" for the grid height, which causes this problem. sorry for the nonsense question. now the real issue is just the alignment.